# WPF Animation Callback Function

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a possibility to register a function to a Animated Usercontroll that is called when the animation is over?

I have a Usercontroll-Animation I start by calling .BeginAnimation(propdp, animation);

How to call another function when the Animation is over?

Comment: Unfortunately the users named below have voted to close your question because they incorrectly assumed that your problem was the same as the post mentioned at the top of your question. I have voted to re-open it, but more votes are needed... come on StackOverflow community... see some sense here please and re-open this question.

Comment: @Sheridan Maybe you should point out what this question makes different from the other - in particular because the answer of afore-mentioned question exactly contains the code snippet to be used. It even links the same documentation than you did.

Comment: +1 @JeffRSon, you are completely correct and I was mistakenly looking at a different question that was `Storyboard` based. I accept that this question is the same as the linked question and retract my previous comment. Thank you for coming back to point that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [`Timeline.Completed` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can use. You can either set it in XAML, or in C# on a `Storyboard` instance. The linked page has a full working example that you can view.

The handler used is the default `EventHandler delegate`:

```
private void StoryboardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // the Storyboard has stopped
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Although the `Completed` event can be set on a `Storyboard` instance, it is in fact defined in the `Timeline` class. As `Timeline` is the base class for all `AnimationTimeline` classes, this means that you can also attach a handler to the `Completed` event from the `AnimationTimeline` object that you are passing into the `BeginAnimation` event.

Comment: What can I do if I don't have a storyboard? The example needs a reference to a storyboard I guess.

Comment: Didn't find the post I duplicated, before I created this. sry.
Anyway, the completed event works fine. thx to JeffRSon as well :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `animation.Completed` event.

Comment: What function do I have to override in my user-control to use it?

Comment: No function has to be overriden. You must set a handler for the Completed event of your animation.